# I'm getting one of those Fiddler port 8888 is in use messages

Tags: networking

It suggests I use a different one.  My first question is, which different one do I specify?  I'm afraid of screwing something up by just arbitrarily specifying '8889' or something.

My second question is:  I'm a little unnerved by the fact I was using Fiddler successfully just last week but this week something new that I don't know about is now "listening" (quote/unquote) on port 8888, according to NETSTAT -A.  How can I find out what this other thing that's now listening in on port 8888 is?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `netstat` command is your friend.  Check the documentation for more information.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true

EDIT: It seems that you have edited your original post to include the netstat command.  If it doesn't appear in the netstat command then you may have a rootkit that is using port 8888.  But this is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.  8888 does appear in NETSTAT -A as line item: TCP 127.0.0.1:8888 Admin-THINK:0 LISTENING

Comment: Okay, it was an Intel Service Manager daemon using port 8888. I stopped that process, and now Fiddler loads fine. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Just so you know, you will not mess anything up by using another port.  But you will have to redirect anything attempting to connect to your service to the new port.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just vaguely aware that there is a standard usage for ports, that some ranges are reserved for some things and others for others.  And some are set aside for whatever.  Are there a few that you know about that could safely be said are free to use for this purpose if I need to down the line?

Comment: Anything above 1024 is free to use for any reason.

Comment: Thank you.  If I NETSTAT -A and it gives me a list of stuff, can I use anything above 1024 minus those >1024 listed in NETSTAT -A, or is there a more comprehensive flag that returns more line items already in use?